# write a post curl in java

Tags: java, curl

I am trying to write a post curl in java.
my curl is:

```
curl -X PUT -u username:password http://localhost:1234/api/2.0/data1/include/value1
```

I wrote in java:

```
String stringUrl = "http://localhost:1234/api/2.0/data1/include/value1";
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

        uc.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "Curl");

        String userpass = "username" + ":" + "password";
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
        uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
```

Interestingly, it did not give any error but nothing happened and value1 did not add to input 1 so it means the curl post that I wrote did not do anything. Can anyone be kind enough to help me convert the above post curl request to java code?

Answer (score 1):

For better invoking HTTP methods use Apache HttpClient.

Here is a nice overview how to start with get and post method:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheHttpClient/article.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to call: uc.setDoOutput(true); before trying to set any http headers with setRequestProperty() See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html